# My website looks very different on Firefox.. Can't pinpoint why

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

This is my website http://aaronisdead.com/sites/dejatest/deja.html

When viewed in Chrome, it looks almost exactly what I want it to. In Firefox, all of the text is in the center of the page instead of the center of divs. There's also a problem with the filter that causes every div to appear black(a big problem when the entire site is pictures)

HTML Structure

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="row">
            <div class="cell A1"><img class="spacer" src="spacer.png"><div id="text">MIKEY<br/><p>SPINDRIFT KIOSK</p>DIGITAL COLLAGE</div></div>
            <div class="cell A2"><img class="spacer" src="spacer.png"><div id="text">ERIC<br/><p>LIZ & RYAN HEMSWORTH</p>ALBUM DESIGN</div></div>
            <div class="cell A3"><img class="spacer" src="spacer.png"><div id="text">MIKEY<br/><p>EPHEMERA</p>DIGITAL COLLAGE</div></div>
            <div class="cell A4"><img class="spacer" src="spacer.png"><div id="text">ERIC<br/><p>REJJIE SNOW</p>SITE DESIGN</div></div>
            </div>
```

This is just one row, there are three more with the exact same structure

CSS:
I've reduced a lot of the code into just the code for one row for simplicity reasons

```
.A1, .A2, .A3, .A4 {
        position:relative;
        }

        .A1:before, .A2:before, .A3:before, .A4:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .2s ease-in-out;
        filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
        filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%) brightness(30%); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */ 
        z-index: -1;
        }

        .A1:before {background-image:url('spindrift.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
        .A2:before {background-image:url('daynnite.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
        .A3:before {background-image:url('ephemera.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
        .A4:before {background-image:url('rejjiesnow.jpg'); background-size:cover;}


        .A1:hover:before, .A2:hover:before, .A3:hover:before, .A4:hover:before, {
        -webkit-filter:none;
        }

            /* text hover */
        div.cell:hover #text{
        opacity:0;
        filter: none;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
        transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        }

        #text{
        opacity:1;
        display:table;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:999;
        color:#ffffff;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
        top:44%;
        left:0;
        filter: none;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
        transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        font:12px ProximaNovaRegular, sans serif;
        text-decoration:none;
        }

        p {
        font:16px ProximaNovaBold, sans serif;
        margin:0;
        padding:1 0 1 0;
        }
/*Table rules*/
    .container{
            display:table-row;
            width:100%;
            }

        .row{
        display:table-row;
        width:100%;
        }

        .cell{
        position:relative;
        display:table-cell;
        width:700px;
        height:auto;
        transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        }

        html{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        }

        body{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-color:black;
        color:black;
        }

    /* hover */

div.cell:hover {
filter: none;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
opacity:1.0;
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this and I hate asking such a vague question here so I've included a lot of code..If `.cell {display:table-cell;}` is disabled, the site turns into something recognizable. I realize there's a grayscale filter that's not working on Firefox, but my main concern here is getting the text in the center of the divs.

Feel free to check out the source code on the actual site.

Comment: Anywhere you're using -webkit- specific CSS, make sure you're using a version that targets Firefox and IE also (I can see you seem to have some webkit specific stuff) and then it'll work fine in all of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a `doctype` tag first in your document. Right now you have nothing that tells the browser what HTML version you want to use, so it will use Quirks mode, which is basically to be compatible with the oldest browser that you can imagine.

Your HTML markup is invalid, at least for the HTML version used. You have `<div>` elements inside `<a>` elements, and that is only allowed in HTML 5. Unless you have a `doctype` tag that says that you are using HTML 5, the browser will try to fix the markup, for example by moving the `div` outside the `a`.

Your markup has other errors, for example elements nested wrong. You have elements nested like this:

```
<div>
  <a>
    <img>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

As you see, the `div` and `a` ending tags are in the wrong order.

You have the style sheed completely outside the HTML document. It should be inside the `<head>` tag.

The `<head>` and `<title>` tags are missing. They are required elements in an HTML document.

Fixing these issues will give you the basics for getting a consistent result in different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Remove from your `#text`

```
position:absolute
```

I tested on FF28 and it works.

Let me know if this is what you want.

and your background its not showing in FF, try adding all Vendors in your background-image:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Comment: I tried this and I do think you might be on to something, but when inspecting the elements or by highlighting I can see that this actually positions the text outside of the div cells in between rows. this mangles the whole div positioning up

Comment: Look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22885707/3448527 from @Guffa. You are missing the essential.. Doctype and your HTML is not valid in some parts. Fix that and then test it

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a doctype so you are in 'quirks mode' and it's like 1995 all over again and no two browsers may look the same. All new web pages MUST have a doctype. Use this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That will put all browsers into 'standards mode'.

Unfortunately, because you didn't start out in standards mode, this may make your page move around a bit and look different than it does now but it must be done.

In addition, your markup is invalid cause you put your script tags outside of the html element. The html element is, essentially, the document itself and you can't do that.

For a complete list of all your errors, [plug in your site link here.](http://validator.w3.org/) Right now, it shows 98 HTML errors alone.

Comment: Wish I could upvote you 1,000 times for the validator.. Going to make learning this stuff crazy easier.